# How do I convert from a location (address) String to a YGeoPoint in Yahoo Maps API?

Tags: api, yahoo-maps

I have a list of addresses from a Database for which I'd like to put markers on a Yahoo Map. The [`addMarker()` method](http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/ajax/V3.8/index.html#YMap) on YMap takes a YGeoPoint, which requires a latitude and longitude. However, Yahoo Maps must know how to convert from addresses because `drawZoomAndCenter(LocationType,ZoomLevel)` can take an address. I could convert by using `drawZoomAndCenter()` then `getCenterLatLon()` but is there a better way, which doesn't require a draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask the map object to do the geoCoding, and catch the callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map = new YMap(document.getElementById('map'));
map.drawZoomAndCenter("Algeria", 17);

map.geoCodeAddress("Cambridge, UK");

YEvent.Capture(map, EventsList.onEndGeoCode, function(geoCode) {
    if (geoCode.success)
        map.addOverlay(new YMarker(geoCode.GeoPoint));
});
</script>
```

One thing to beware of -- in this example the `drawAndZoom` call will itself make a geoCoding request, so you'll get the callback from that too. You might want to filter that out, or set the map's centre based on a GeoPoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with U.S. addresses, you can use [geocoder.us](http://geocoder.us/), which has [APIs](http://geocoder.us/help/).

Also, *Google Maps Hacks* has a hack, ["Hack 62. Find the Latitude and Longitude of a Street Address"](http://safari.oreilly.com/0596101619/googlemapshks-CHP-7-SECT-2), for that.

Comment: This is only readable if you have a Safari account - so no use to me.